# How to split fields using a delimiter and insert into new fields using Ingest Node in ELK?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have an index out of which, one of my fields, let's say field_a is mm/dash/live/7047/LIVESERVICE_7001/TG_STB_HD.mpd.

I want to use the ingest node to split this field with the separator "/" and insert the array of values into several different fields within that index.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Below code splits the field into an array.

```
filter {
    mutate {
        split => ["field_a" , "/" ]
    }
}
```